# JavaFX - Is there a way to add or modify Media file Metadata?

Tags: file, javafx, tags, metadata, media

I'm developing a program where I can upload some MP3 audio files and they are sent to a Server via SFTP.

Since there is the possibility to retrieve File Metadata Tags with the Statement:

```
getMedia().getMetadata();
```

I was wondering if there was a way, even an external Library or API, to insert or edit Metadata Tags for a specific file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/

Comment: https://github.com/mpatric/mp3agic